# How to show the build ant script that IBM RAD 9.1 use to build a Websphere Application project?

Tags: build, ant, websphere, ibm-rad

I can build my project successful in IBM RAD, but I got error when I build using ant script by myself. So I want to know the build script that IBM RAD used. How can I check it ?

Update my question: How can I show or modify build file or Java builder in RAD as attached image [image]

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse (and thus RAD) does not use ant to build projects, it uses one or more things things called builders.  For example the Java Builder is used to translate Java source files into .class files.  You can see this by selecting a project in your workspace, left click and select Properties, then Builders

Comment: Thanks @F Rowe, Do you know how to fix this error ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48163497/javac-createprocess-error-206-the-filename-or-extension-is-too-long/48175807#48175807